# Need a dax code in order to use scater plot for fix area

Tags: powerbi, dax, scatter-plot

I have a challenge to produce a some activity data based on their respective flags. But the calculations are slightly complex and I don't know how I will do that in Power BI using dax or M query. Attached grid is the challenge i want to show the data point based on its Stage and color eg is task is flagged as S1 and color is green it should only appear in the respective section.  Any idea will be welcome how to achieve this. I am using Power BI server so limited on the choice of visuals and approaches I can take to achieve this task. [image]

Once data is entered and showed using scatter plot result should something similar like below image. [image]

Comment: Can you share some data ?